# Why does set_lorder not work on libdb5.3?

Tags: c, database

I have the following code to create and insert 3 values into a libdb database.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <db.h>

int main() {
    DB *dbp;    // Database pointer
    DBT key, data;  // Key and data containers
    int ret;
    
    // Open the database
    ret = db_create(&dbp, NULL, 0);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create DB: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Set the byte order
    ret = dbp->set_lorder(dbp, 4321);  // 1234 for little-endian, 4321 for big-endian
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to set byte order: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
        dbp->close(dbp, 0);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    // Open the database with specific flags and file name
    ret = dbp->open(dbp, NULL, "test.db", NULL, DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE , 0);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open DB: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
        dbp->close(dbp, 0);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    // Initialize the key and data containers
    memset(&key, 0, sizeof(DBT));
    memset(&data, 0, sizeof(DBT));
    
    // Insert integer values into the database
    int values[] = {1, 127, 257};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        key.data = &values[i];
        key.size = sizeof(int);
        data.data = &values[i];
        data.size = sizeof(int);
        
        ret = dbp->put(dbp, NULL, &key, &data, DB_NOOVERWRITE);
        if (ret == DB_KEYEXIST) {
            printf("Key already exists: %d\n", values[i]);
        } else if (ret != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to insert data: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
        } else {
            printf("Inserted value: %d\n", values[i]);
        }
    }
    
    // Close the database
    dbp->close(dbp, 0);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Inserted value: 1
Inserted value: 127
Inserted value: 257.

The program to read the database is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <db.h>

int main() {
    DB *dbp;    // Database pointer
    DBT key, data;  // Key and data containers
    int ret;
    
    // Open the database
    ret = db_create(&dbp, NULL, 0);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create DB: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    // Open the database with specific flags and file name
    ret = dbp->open(dbp, NULL, "test.db", NULL, DB_BTREE, 0, 0);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open DB: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    // Initialize the key and data containers
    memset(&key, 0, sizeof(DBT));
    memset(&data, 0, sizeof(DBT));
    
    // Initialize the cursor
    DBC *cursor;
    ret = dbp->cursor(dbp, NULL, &cursor, 0);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create cursor: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
        dbp->close(dbp, 0);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    // Read and output keys
    while ((ret = cursor->c_get(cursor, &key, &data, DB_NEXT)) == 0) {
        printf("Key: %d\n", *(int *)key.data);
}
    
    if (ret != DB_NOTFOUND) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while reading: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
    }
    
    // Close the cursor and the database
    cursor->c_close(cursor);
    dbp->close(dbp, 0);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The program runs with output:
Key: 1
Key: 257
Key: 127

I expected 1, 127, and 257.

I am sure it had to do with endianess. I have tried the set_lorder call with 1234 and 4321 with the exact same result. I am running this on a 2012 Macbook Pro, running Ubuntu.

What gives? Again this is libdb5.3, which I believe is the last Sleepycat release before big O bought it.

It seems the `set_lorder` call has no effect. I deleted the database before trying `set_lorder` with 1234.

I have kludged the code,adding a call in the insert program:

```
        temp=htobe32(values[i]);
```

and in the read program:

```
    printf("Key: %i\n", be32toh(*(int *)key.data));
```

I could have also output the values as a string, but I should not have to do this.